# Cancel request in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `http` package in flutter to send http request, for uploading and downloading I am using `client.send` and `MultipartRequest`

I want to know is it possible to cancel upload/download request without closing client `client.close`?

Answer (score 1):

Even though Dio is built on the http package, somehow it manages to provide a token that you can use to cancel a request in progress.  You might want to look at that.

Comment: can you pls help with code example?